# Adding to database with multiple text boxes

Tags: php, mysql, post

What I am trying to do with this script is allow users to update a url for their websites, and since each user isn't going to have the same amount of websites is is hard for me to just add `$_POST['website']` for each of these.

Here is the script

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("header.php");
include("functions.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['password'])){
    header("Location: pubs.php");
    }

$getmember = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `publishers` WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$info = mysql_fetch_array($getmember);
$getsites = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `websites` WHERE publisher = '".$info['username']."'");

$postback = $_POST['website'];
$webname = $_POST['webid'];
if($_POST['submit']){
foreach ( $_POST['website'] as $key => $value )
{
 $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `websites` SET `postback` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($postback[$value])."' WHERE id = '$webname'");
}
}


print"
<div id='center'>
<span id='tools_lander'><a href='export.php'>Export Campaigns</a></span>
<div id='calendar_holder'>
<h3>Please define a postback for each of your websites below. The following variables should be used when creating your postback.<br />
cid = Campaign ID<br />
sid = Sub ID<br />
rate = Campaign Rate<br />
status = Status of Lead. 1 means payable 2 mean reversed<br />
A sample postback URL would be <br />
http://www.example.com/postback.php?cid=#cid&sid=#sid&rate=#rate&status=#status</h3>
<table class='balances' align='center'>
<form method='POST' action=''>";

while($website = mysql_fetch_array($getsites)){
print"
<tr>
<input type ='hidden' name='webid' value='".$website['id']."' />
<td style='font-weight:bold;'>".$website['name']."'s Postback:</td>
<td><input type='text' style='width:400px;' name='website[]' value='".$website['postback']."' /></td>
</tr>";
}
print"
<td style='float:right;position:relative;left:150px;'><input type='submit' name='submit' style='font-size:15px;height:30px;width:100px;' value='Submit' /></td>
</form>
</table>
</div>";

include("footer.php");
?>
```

What I am attempting to do insert the what is inputted in the text boxes to their corresponding websites, and I cannot think of any other way to do it, and this obviously does not works and returns a notice stating `Array to string conversion`
If there is a more logical way to do this please let me know.

**UPDATE**
I added a foreach statement, but this still doesn't seem to solve the problem. It doesn't update anything in the database.

Comment: You are using [an obsolete database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also exposing yourself to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/) that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: As you can see from the `var_dump( $_POST['website'] );` that its an array because your using `website[]` in the form, just loop though it with a foreach

Comment: @Quentin this is just using XAMPP at the moment, I have functions to help against SQL injections, but that is completely off topic from the questions I asked.

Comment: I have updated the OP with a foreach statement that does no good either. I have tried both `$postback[$key]` and `$postback[$value]`

Comment: Try just $value insted of $postback[$value]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem with some trial and error, Lawrence helped with the informing me to use a foreach statement. This is what I have ended up with.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("header.php");
include("functions.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['password'])){
    header("Location: pubs.php");
    }

$getmember = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `publishers` WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$info = mysql_fetch_array($getmember);
$getsites = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `websites` WHERE publisher = '".$info['username']."'");

$postback = $_POST['website'];
$webname = $_POST['webid'];
if($_POST['submit']){
$i = -1;
foreach ($postback as $key => $value)
{
$i ++;
print_r($webname[$i]);
 $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `websites` SET `postback` = '".cleanQuery($postback[$key])."' WHERE `id` = '".$webname[$i]."'") or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
}
}



print"
<div id='center'>
<span id='tools_lander'><a href='export.php'>Export Campaigns</a></span>
<div id='calendar_holder'>
<h3>Please define a postback for each of your websites below. The following variables should be used when creating your postback.<br />
cid = Campaign ID<br />
sid = Sub ID<br />
rate = Campaign Rate<br />
status = Status of Lead. 1 means payable 2 mean reversed<br />
A sample postback URL would be <br />
http://www.example.com/postback.php?cid=#cid&sid=#sid&rate=#rate&status=#status</h3>
<table class='balances' align='center'>
<form method='POST' action=''>";

while($website = mysql_fetch_array($getsites)){
print"
<tr>
<input type ='hidden' name='webid[]' value='".$website['id']."' />
<td style='font-weight:bold;'>".$website['name']."'s Postback:</td>
<td><input type='text' style='width:400px;' name='website[]' value='".$website['postback']."' /></td>
</tr>";
}
print"
<td style='float:right;position:relative;left:150px;'><input type='submit' name='submit' style='font-size:15px;height:30px;width:100px;' value='Submit' /></td>
</form>
</table>
</div>";

include("footer.php");
?>
```